# Regular expression for matching id selector using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In my program , i want to validate id of html tags..
To my functions id is passed as a string preceeding with  #..
I found that ,rules for naming and id in HTML are,

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
  So i written the following regular expression.

  /(^|\s)(#{1})([a-zA-Z])([^a-zA-Z0-9]{0})/g;

But it is giving me wrong results.What's wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: What results do you get?  Could you provide some sample input and corresponding output?

Comment: Note that many of these restrictions have been removed in html 5.

Comment: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class
ya got it....

Answer (score 2):

```
/#[a-z][\w\d-]*\b/gi
```

- `\w` signifies letters from a-z, A-Z and underscore (_)
- `\d` signifies whole numbers from 0-9
- `\b` signifies a word boundary
- the `i` flag is to catch the first letter regardless of case

**EDIT:** Sorry for forgetting the boundary in the beginning of the group.

```
var str = '#sss #s23 dd#ww';
// #ww will be omitted because # is not the
// first char in the char group there.
var rx = /(^|\s)(#[a-z][\w\d-]*)\b/gi;
var arr = [];
str.replace(rx, function(){arr.push(arguments[2])});
// this is just to catch the id's.
// it won't modify str.
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
/^#[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_-]*$/i
```

Comment: this gives me correct result..but [a-z0-9_-] same as [^a-z0-9_-]{0}?.
then why am i getting wrong results?

Comment: @JinuJD: no, oblivious not the same

Comment: Your solution with {0} is completly different from mine. I must say i struggle to understand what is the possibile result with your regex

Comment: it should contain zero occurances of non alphanumeric_- at the end
which is same as alphanumeric_- characters at the end